# The Content of the Popup don't Display after Pressing the Textlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Goal:
Display the popup screen Search5 by clicking on the arrow icon in relation to the link textlink "test".

Firstly, click on the textlink test, then click on the displayed icon arrow and then the popup screen Search will appear.

Problem:
When you click on the linktext "test" the icon will appear. When you click on the icon, the content of the popup Search will not appear.

What code am I missing? I have tried with different solution but I failed.

Compare the the third row from the table, the icon works that you can show the content of the popup search.

Info:
*Im using bootstrap 3

Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title></title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
  <table class="table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Search</th>
     <th>Test</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="datafromtbody">
    <tr id="tr_row1">
     <td id="tr_row1_td1"></td>
     <td><a href="#myModal-firstdata" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-firstdata" class="firstdata" id="data_1">test</a></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td id="tr_row2_td2"></td>      
     <td><a href="#myModal-firstdata" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-firstdata" class="firstdata" id="data_2">test</a></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_row3">
     <td id="tr_row2_td3">
      <a href="#myModal-search5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-search5" class="showseconddata" id="data_3">
       <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aiga-symbol-signs/581/aiga_uparrow_inv-512.png" width="15" height="15" />
      </a>
     </td>          
     <td></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>  

   
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-firstdata" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
   <!-- Modal content-->
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     <h4 class="modal-title">First data</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <div id="firstdata_content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>  
   
   
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-search5" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
   <!-- Modal content-->
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     <h4 class="modal-title">Search 5</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <div id="showdatafor5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>  
   

 <script>
   
  $('.firstdata').click(function () {

      var alldata = $(this).attr("id");
   var number = alldata.split('_')[1];
  
   var display ="<table><thead><tr><th>a</th><th>b</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
   
   display +="<tr>";
   display +="<td>a</td><td><button onclick='createicon(" + number + ")'>add data in table</button></td>";
   display +="</tr>";
   
   display +="</tbody></table>";


   var anydata = document.getElementById("firstdata_content");
   anydata.innerHTML = display;
  }); 
  

  function createicon(data)
  {
   var idname = "tr_row" + data + "_td" + data;
  
   var anydata = document.getElementById(idname);
  
   if (anydata.innerHTML === "") {
    var addData = document.getElementById(idname);
    
    addData.innerHTML = "<a href='#myModal-search5' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal-search5' class='showseconddata'><img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aiga-symbol-signs/581/aiga_uparrow_inv-512.png' width='15' height='15' /></a>";   
   } 
  }
  

  $('.showseconddata').click(function () {

   var display ="<table><thead><tr><th>a</th><th>b</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
   
   display +="<tr>";
   display +="<td>show data</td>";
   display +="<td>show data</td>";  
   display +="</tr>";
   
   display +="</tbody></table>";


   var anydata = document.getElementById("showdatafor5");
   anydata.innerHTML = display;
  }); 

  </script> 
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new icons are created after you attached the click event handler to **.showseconddata**. Hence, you need to [delegate](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) this event, changing from:

```
$('.showseconddata').click(function () {
```

to:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.showseconddata', function () {
```

```js
function createicon(data) {
    var idname = "tr_row" + data + "_td" + data;
    var anydata = document.getElementById(idname);

    if (anydata.innerHTML === "") {
        var addData = document.getElementById(idname);

        addData.innerHTML = "<a href='#myModal-search5' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal-search5' class='showseconddata'><img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aiga-symbol-signs/581/aiga_uparrow_inv-512.png' width='15' height='15' /></a>";
    }
}
$('.firstdata').click(function () {
    var alldata = $(this).attr("id");
    var number = alldata.split('_')[1];

    var display ="<table><thead><tr><th>a</th><th>b</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
    display +="<tr>";
    display +="<td>a</td><td><button onclick='createicon(" + number + ")'>add data in table</button></td>";
    display +="</tr>";
    display +="</tbody></table>";

    var anydata = document.getElementById("firstdata_content");
    anydata.innerHTML = display;
});


$('.container').on('click', '.showseconddata', function () {
    var display ="<table><thead><tr><th>a</th><th>b</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

    display +="<tr>";
    display +="<td>show data</td>";
    display +="<td>show data</td>";
    display +="</tr>";
    display +="</tbody></table>";

    var anydata = document.getElementById("showdatafor5");
    anydata.innerHTML = display;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Search</th>
            <th>Test</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="datafromtbody">
        <tr id="tr_row1">
            <td id="tr_row1_td1"></td>
            <td><a href="#myModal-firstdata" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-firstdata" class="firstdata" id="data_1">test</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="tr_row2_td2"></td>
            <td><a href="#myModal-firstdata" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-firstdata" class="firstdata" id="data_2">test</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr_row3">
            <td id="tr_row2_td3">
                <a href="#myModal-search5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-search5" class="showseconddata" id="data_3">
                    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aiga-symbol-signs/581/aiga_uparrow_inv-512.png" width="15" height="15" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-firstdata" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">First data</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="firstdata_content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-search5" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Search 5</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="showdatafor5"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```